# How can I detect a space or newline at the end of scanf()?

Tags: c, io, newline, scanf, space

I'm writing a program where I have to accept commands from the user like a shell where the user can set values for environment variables. The problem I'm having is if the user types `set var var-value` I need to know the user typed a space instead of just `set` and pressed enter which is a different command. How can I determine if the user pressed space or enter using `scanf()`?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  The `scanf` function won't even return until the user presses enter.  Are you saying the user can enter `set` on one line and the remainder of the command on another?

Comment: Doesn't `scanf()` return when it detects a space as well?

Comment: So if the user inputs `set var var-value`, it only places `set` into the variable passed to `scanf()` but doesn't return until the end of `var-value` when the user presses enter?

Comment: It would depend on the format string you're passing to `scanf`.  In general, I don't think `scanf` is the function you want to use here.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll know the user pressed enter because `scanf()` won't return until the user does so.  If you're trying to read characters in real time as the user types, `scanf()` will not work for you.  You will need to use the `getchar()`, `getch()` or `getche()` functions, or a function provided by the OS for reading keyboard input.  Read the characters one by one into an array, scanning for spaces and the enter key as you read.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr).

Comment: `getchar()` interacts with `stdin` like `scanf()`.  Recommend removing it from the list of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with [isspace()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) function in ctype.h

Another way you can use [strchr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to find whether input consists '\n' or space

```
if(strchr(input,'\n')==NULL && strchr(input,' ')==NULL)
{
//do something
}
```

**EDIT**

scanf() reads input till occurrence of any  white space character. After white space ignores input.

Use [fgets()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) Instead of scanf() 
 if you enter input of length less than MAXLENGTH , `'\n'` stays before Null character

Replace it with null character

```
char input[MAXLENGTH+1];  

fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);

if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n')     
input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
```

Comment: `scanf()` will not return the whitespace or newline into `input`

Comment: But `scanf` will drop all whitespace in most cases.  You would need to show how to prevent that from happening for your solution to work.

Comment: @ngneema and Carey Gregory. added some more info. yes, scanf won't read after space or return key. OP need to use fgets() instead of scanf().

Answer (score 1):

You would use `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I detect a space or newline at the end of scanf()?

Use `%width[^\n]` to read input up to a `'\n'`.

```
char buffer[256];
//                  v------- Read and discard leading whitespace
int retval = scanf(" %255[^\n]", buffer);
if (retval != 1) {
  ; // handle error or EOF
}
// Now scan buffer for whatever input format you desire
char ch;
retval = sscanf(buffer, "set%c", &ch);
if ((retval == 1) && (ch == '\n')) {
  ; // deal with "set"
}
else {
  char var[256];
  char value[256];
  retval = sscanf(buffer, "set %s %s", var, value);
  if (retval == 2)  {
    ; // deal with "set var var-value"
  }
  else {
  // other parsings
  }
}
```

Comment: `%s[^\n]`, not `%s[\n]`

Comment: @Sebi2020 Yes, answer amended.