# stop condition when dynamically allocating memory for an array in c

Tags: c

I am getting an array from the input, and when there is no more memory I allocate more (I can't use realloc). my problem is that I do not know what to put as a stop condition for the loop. I want it to stop taking input when I press enter, but it just waits for more.(I am supposed to use scanf)

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define CHUNK 5
int main()
{
    int *arr, allocate_size=0, i, j, k, temp=0, *p, len=0;
    printf("Enter array: ");
    for(i=0,j=0;temp!='\n';i++){
        if(i>=allocate_size){
            allocate_size+= ((++j)*CHUNK);
            p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*allocate_size);
            if(p==NULL){
                printf("Error");
                return 1;
            }
            for(k=0;k<i && i!=0;k++){ /*copying array*/
                p[k]=arr[k];
            }
            free(arr);
            arr = p;
        }
        if(!scanf(" %d", &temp)){
            printf("Invalid input");
            return 1;
        }
        if(temp!='\n'){
            arr[i] = temp;
            len++;
        }
    }
    printf("length is %d\n", len);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18989659/3316645) on a related question, I think it might help you.

Comment: Use `fgets` and then `sscanf`, but check if the first character is `'\n'` before passing to `sscanf` for `int` conversion to break the loop on [Enter] alone. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) You can look at the answer by chux in the link provided in the comment above (not the chosen answer) Be aware that `!scanf(" %d", &temp)` will not catch `EOF`, always validate equal to the number of conversions, e.g. `scanf(" %d", &temp) != 1`

Comment: `arr` is used while uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to take user input is to read an entire line of input at a time with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. The reason for this is you consume an entire line of input with each read and what remains in `stdin` does not depend on the `scanf` *conversion specifier* used. It also eliminates having to remember which *conversion specifiers* consume leading whitespace and those that do not and eliminates characters left in `stdin` on a *matching failure*.

It also provides the convenience of being able to check if the first character in the buffer used to hold the input is `'\n'` telling you that <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone was pressed without any other input.

To incorporate the use of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` in your code, simply declare a buffer to hold a line of user input sufficient for whatever the user may enter (or what results if a cat steps on the keyboard) -- don't skimp on buffer size. Then read the input into the buffer with `fgets()` and check if the first character is `'\n'` to determine if <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone was pressed.

You can do that as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    ...
        if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {  /* read line of input/validate */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (buf[0] == '\n')     /* break loop on [Enter] alone */
            break;
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
    ...
```

(**note:** the check of `sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp) != 1` will catch a manually generated `EOF` if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows) where `!sscanf(buf, " %d", &temp)` won't)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Edit Per-Comment**

Since in your question you indicate you have to allocate dynamically for each integer read, but you cannot use `realloc` to resize your array, the only logical presumption for the dual pointers `arr` and `p` is that you are supposed to manually implement `realloc` by allocating storage each time with `p`, saving the pointer to the allocated block by assignment from `arr = p;` at the end of each iteration so you can copy from `arr` to the new `p` you allocate on the next iteration and then freeing `arr` before you assign `arr = p;` again to prevent *memory leaks*.

Putting the above solution together with the code you posted, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK  5
#define MAXC 256

int main (void)
{
    char buf[MAXC] = "";        /* buffer to hold each line */
    int *arr = NULL,            /* pointer to block holding final array */
        *p = NULL,              /* temp pointer to allocate for each number */
        allocate_size = 0,      /* tracks length of array */
        temp = 0;               /* temp value for integer conversion */

    printf ("Enter %d elements of array:\n\n  arr[%d]: ", CHUNK, allocate_size);

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* read user input into buf */
        int rtn;                        /* variable to hold sscanf return */

        if (*buf == '\n')               /* check if ENTER alone */
            break;                      /* break loop if so */

        /* use sscanf to convert to int, saving return */
        if ((rtn = sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp)) == 1) {
            /* allocate new storage for allocate_size + 1 integers */
            if (!(p = malloc ((allocate_size + 1) * sizeof *p))) {
                perror ("malloc-p");
                break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < allocate_size; i++) /* copy arr to p */
                p[i] = arr[i];
            p[allocate_size++] = temp;  /* add new element at end */

            free (arr);                 /* free old block of memory */
            arr = p;                    /* assign new block to arr */
        }
        else if (rtn == EOF) {  /* manual EOF generated */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else {  /* not an integer value */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        }

        if (allocate_size < CHUNK)  /* if arr not full, prompt for next */
            printf ("  arr[%d]: ", allocate_size);
        else
            break;                  /* done */
    }

    /* output results */
    printf ("\nlength is %d\n", allocate_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < allocate_size; i++)
        printf (" %d", arr[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    free (arr);     /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Without stopping or error:

```
$ ./bin/arrnorealloc
Enter 5 elements of array:

  arr[0]: 10
  arr[1]: 20
  arr[2]: 30
  arr[3]: 40
  arr[4]: 50

length is 5
 10 20 30 40 50
```

Stopping early:

```
$ ./bin/arrnorealloc
Enter 5 elements of array:

  arr[0]: 10
  arr[1]: 20
  arr[2]:

length is 2
 10 20
```

Handling user error:

```
$ ./bin/arrnorealloc
Enter 5 elements of array:

  arr[0]: 10
  arr[1]: 20
  arr[2]: dogs
error: invalid integer input.
  arr[2]: 30
  arr[3]: fish
error: invalid integer input.
  arr[3]: 40
  arr[4]: 50

length is 5
 10 20 30 40 50
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

Most importantly when allocating memory dynamically, the error check:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arrnorealloc
==5555== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5555== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5555== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5555== Command: ./bin/arrnorealloc
==5555==
Enter 5 elements of array:

  arr[0]: 10
  arr[1]: 20
  arr[2]: 30
  arr[3]: 40
  arr[4]: 50

length is 5
 10 20 30 40 50
==5555==
==5555== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5555==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5555==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 2,108 bytes allocated
==5555==
==5555== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5555==
==5555== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5555== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Comment: `arr[i]` in first iteration of loop use uninitialized. Is it OK?

Comment: NO. before `p[k]=arr[k];`, `arr` must point to a valid and initialized block of memory. How do you expect to assign a value to `p[k]` from an uninitialized `arr[k]`?? What is you `arr` supposed to point to?

Comment: because I don't see any `malloc()` for arr pointer. I think this code in original question not yours, is wrong. Could you please clarify it for me?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute and I'll trim what you have down to something that works.